# Convert Django ModelForm to use User object

Tags: python, django, user-input, django-forms, django-users

I'm creating a registration form for my site.

I'm going with just the standard field entries of `username, email, password` in my `User` object.

The database tables are already created.

**Models.py**

```
class RegistrationForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
```

**views.py**

```
def Registration(request):
    RegForm = RegistrationForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if RegForm.is_valid():
            newUser = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)

            RegForm.save()
            try:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/Newuser/?userNm=' + clearUserName)
            except:
                raise ValidationError(('Invalid request'), code='300')    ## [ TODO ]: add a custom error page here.
```

My question is, how do I represent these fields:

```
username, email, password
```

in this line (from the view):

```
newUser = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
```

that are part of the `RegistrationForm()` in models.py ?

Additionally: How do I properly represent this default model (`User`) in the `modelform` in forms.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your second question:

Use `UserCreationForm` to represent registration process for `User` class, it handles validation and saving for you and you can always extend it (i.e. to add email field)

`User` class has a lot of related forms, depending of the use case: authentication, registration, password change etc. read the docs on authentication to find more.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.forms

Comment: Great link here. I will give this a whirl. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get the validated data from the form using cleaned_date:

```
username = form.cleaned_data['username']
email = form.cleaned_data['email']
password = form.cleaned_data['password']

newUser = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
```

Now I think your approach has serious problems since you are saving the form again after creating the user object, also the User object expects the password field to be a hash of the password and some meta data, etc.
I highly recommend you use [django-registration](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/) (or at least have a look at it) which handles all this stuff for you in addition to email validation, all you need is to provide the templates(and also you can find some templates for it like [this](https://github.com/macdhuibh/django-registration-templates) )